# JSF - SelectItem - and converted to &amp;

Tags: jsf-2

I am using `<f:selectItem>`. It is populated with a value 'a and b'. In the dropdown list, the value is shown as 'a and b', but when this value is selected, it gets converted to 'a '& amp ;' b'.

xhtml:

```
<f:selectItems name="motivationType" 
               id="motivationTypeOptions"
               value="#{promotionDetailManagedBean.motivationTypeSelectList}">
</f:selectItems>
```

bean :

```
private List<SelectItem> motivationTypeSelectList;
```

where the elements of the list are populated as

```
selectItemList.add(new SelectItem(key.toString(), paramMap.get(key)));
```

where paramMap is Map

How to disable this conversion?

Comment: Show us some code please

Comment: how do you create the `motivationTypeSelectList`?Do you set the itemLabel and itemValue?

Comment: I use SelectItem(value,label).

Comment: Your question is not clear! You should re-explain. You can disable the conversion of label by using the attribute `itemLabelEscaped` in `f:selectItems`

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. Please provide an SSCCE. That's the smallest possible, but **complete** code of the XHTML file and Java class. Also please mention the JSF impl/version used.